# '80s–'90s anime about robot fairies fighting

Tags: story-identification, anime, robots, fairy

I've been trying to find the name of an anime from my childhood. From what I can remember, the main plot was basically about like these fairy-like robots fighting in a tournament. Sorry if the description may be too vague, but this is literally all I can remember.

Comment: How were they like fairies? Wings? Tails? Pixe dust?

Comment: Were they autonomous, piloted or remotely-controlled?  How big were they?  What was the prize?

Comment: Were there humans as well? Were they adults or children?

Comment: Were they called fairies, or something like the angels in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angelic_Layer ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about Magic Knight Rayearth?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to explain why you think _Magic Knight Rayearth_ might be the correct anime, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question. It'd help the rest of us to decide how likely this answer is to be correct, and whether we should therefore upvote it or not.